# Elastic Search Integration With Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, elasticsearch

Hi I am learning elastic search and tried a few getting started with ES tutorials,now I would like to integrate it with Spring MVC, all I found were a few examples on how to integrate with spring data, could you please provide me few simple examples on how to integrate with spring mvc and it would be helpful if you could direct me to some more elastic search tutorials just to get a better idea on how it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good Tutorial for spring data and mvc here (but only in German language):
http://comcepto.de/index.php?option=com_cobalt&view=records&section_id=1:autocomplete-mit-elasticsearch&cat_id=4:spring-mvc-autocomplete&Itemid=157

and here is a good explanation for spring-data:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/

and for spring mvc:
http://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/